# Count how many times a specific Date appears in a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, date, count, repeat

Morning fellas,

I have a variable *convertedObjChart* containing the following code that gets updated every time the frontend user selects a different period:

```
"[{\"ErrorCode\":\"4212\",\"Date\":\"2019-12-17\"},{\"ErrorCode\":\"1\",\"Date\":\"2020-01-23\"},{\"ErrorCode\":\"4233\",\"Date\":\"2020-02-21\"},{\"ErrorCode\":\"4233\",\"Date\":\"2020-02-24\"},{\"ErrorCode\":\"1\",\"Date\":\"2020-07-02\"},{\"ErrorCode\":\"1006\",\"Date\":\"2020-07-15\"},{\"ErrorCode\":\"4245\",\"Date\":\"2020-07-16\"},{\"ErrorCode\":\"9420\",\"Date\":\"2020-08-17\"},{\"ErrorCode\":\"9450\",\"Date\":\"2020-08-17\"},{\"ErrorCode\":\"1\",\"Date\":\"2020-11-09\"},{\"ErrorCode\":\"4\",\"Date\":\"2020-11-09\"},{\"ErrorCode\":\"4245\",\"Date\":\"2020-11-09\"}]";
```

#1: Need to input this JSON string into a multi-line chart, so every ***ErrorCode*** is displayed as a *name* in a line.

#2: Represent on **Y** the number of times an ***ErrorCode*** occurs for that specific Date.

#3: Represent on **X** the label ***Date*** for every single day inside the JSON.

**Q: How do I count how many times a certain day is present inside the JSON?**

Please notice the length of this string changes every time the user updates the chosen period, making it larger or smaller depending on how many errors it found for that period.

This is the chart i'm using for tests (not the correct one since only has a single line):

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
            animationEnabled: true,
            zoomEnabled: true,
            title: {
                text: "Try Zooming and Panning"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints: convertedObjChart,
            }]
        });
      
        chart.render();
```

Comment: First thing you should do is parse the JSON so you have an array of objects...

Comment: Your first step will be to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should convert json into a Object first

```js
const jsonData =
  '[{"ErrorCode":"4212","Date":"2019-12-17"},{"ErrorCode":"1","Date":"2020-01-23"},{"ErrorCode":"4233","Date":"2020-02-21"},{"ErrorCode":"4233","Date":"2020-02-24"},{"ErrorCode":"1","Date":"2020-07-02"},{"ErrorCode":"1006","Date":"2020-07-15"},{"ErrorCode":"4245","Date":"2020-07-16"},{"ErrorCode":"9420","Date":"2020-08-17"},{"ErrorCode":"9450","Date":"2020-08-17"},{"ErrorCode":"1","Date":"2020-11-09"},{"ErrorCode":"4","Date":"2020-11-09"},{"ErrorCode":"4245","Date":"2020-11-09"}]'

let data = JSON.parse(jsonData)

let calculatedResult = new Object()
data.forEach((d) => {
  calculatedResult[d.Date] = calculatedResult[d.Date]
    ? ++calculatedResult[d.Date]
    : 1
})
console.log(calculatedResult)
/**
it print out { '2019-12-17': 1,
  '2020-01-23': 1,
  '2020-02-21': 1,
  '2020-02-24': 1,
  '2020-07-02': 1,
  '2020-07-15': 1,
  '2020-07-16': 1,
  '2020-08-17': 2,
  '2020-11-09': 3 }
*/
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I set it to only compare the content inside quotes after "Date :" without telling it directly one specific date and add that variable (in this case LEN) to the chart?

Comment: I edited som code, is it what you wanted?